# Can't get Jquery value on php side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an array, it is filled in javascript code. I need to reach the values of this array on php side when confirm button clicked. So, I am using ajax post method as below.It is running successfully, I know because all of the alerts are working successfully. This is js part of my code.

```
$('#firstConfirmButton').click(function(){  

    var my_json_val = JSON.stringify(ordersArray, null);
    alert(my_json_val.toString());

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: my_json_val,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        async: false,
        processData: false,
        success:  function(response){
            //alert("---"+data);
        alert("Settings has been updated successfully.");
        alert(my_json_val);
        alert(response);

        window.location.reload(true);
        }
    }); 


});
```

On the other side, I have a test.php page and also it contains "confirm" button that use the js code above. When this button clicked, I want to echo values of the array that I posted with ajax. But I can not get the values on php side. Here is my php code;

```
<?php


    require("includes/db.php");
    require("includes/functions.php");

    session_start();       

    if (isset($_POST['firstConfirmButton'])) {

        echo 'I am here'; //I can see only this row on php page

        $my_json_encoded = $_POST['data'];
        $my_json_val = json_decode($my_json_encoded);
        echo $my_json_val;  //nothing happens          

    }
```

and here is my html code for confirm button;

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="starbucks.php">
                    <div id="firstConfirmButton">
                        <button type="submit" name="firstConfirmButton"   id="firstConfirmButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Onayla</button>
                    </div>
```

So where is my fault, please help!

Comment: Have you tried echoing $_POST['data']?

Comment: Yes, have you tried $_POST['data'] because $_POST['firstConfirmButton'] holds nothing !

Comment: I think you either shouldn't `JSON.stringify` the object to pass it to `data` in request, or use `json_decode()` in PHP to create data structure from JSON string.

Comment: also check if ```$my_json_val``` is null (that means JSON decode error).

Comment: When you fire the ajax call from the button event $_POST['firstConfirmButton'] can't be set, since that get's transmitted on a different call, i.e. the action perform of the form. But since you do one ajax call with $_POST['firstConfirmButton'] being set and one with $_POST['data'] being set, but none with both set, you get the echo of 'I am here' one time.

Comment: Also: `false` is not a valid value for `contentType`

Comment: @Markai I tried  echoing $_POST['data'] but nothing happened.I read your second comment, it really makes sense but I don't know how I can fix this problem

Comment: @e-nouri I changed it to  $_POST['data']  but nothing happened

Comment: @pawel I already used json-decode. Also I tried passing directly ordersArray instead of JSON.stringify the object but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't cast the array to Json, the ajax post will cast it itself, so replace `my_json_val` by `ordersArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to redirect to your php file or do you just need data from it? Because action="file.php" redirects to this file. If you just need data, try to use jquerys .submit method and do an ajax call, otherwise use it to remaster your action attribute (for simplicity i would use an id on the form if you have multiple forms on your site):

```
$('#yourform').submit(function(){
   var my_json_val = JSON.stringify(ordersArray, null);
   var elem = {
       firstConfirmButton: true, 
       data: my_json_val
   }
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: elem,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        async: false,
        processData: false,
        success:  function(response){
            //alert("---"+data);
            alert("Settings has been updated successfully.");
            alert(my_json_val);
            alert(response);
        }
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

if you actually want to redirect, try using this:

```
$('#yourform').submit(function(ev){
    var my_json_val = JSON.stringify(ordersArray, null);
    $(this).attr('action', ev.target.action+'?data="'+my_json_val+'"');
});
```

Comment: Actually, I just want data to use it for session variables. So I changed my javascript code to submit function as you said above. But I still can't see data on php side. How should I change my html and php code to handle this data?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you check for "firstConfirmButton" to be set?

Comment: How to change your code on server side depends strongly on what you are trying to do with the data your ajax call sends.